# How to make cursor invisible on clicking "GO" button from soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am preparing app using phonegap.In app i have displayed list of data and one search bar.User can search by particular name.Here i have used jquery ajax.It is working fine.My problem is when click on search bar soft keyboard will open automatically.After enter the text just click on "GO" button in soft keyboard i call search method.It is also working fine.But cursor is still visible on search bar.I want to make the cursor invisible on clicking "GO" button from soft keyboard.My code is,

```
   function submitOnEnter(inputElement, event) 
 {  
  console.log("KEY OCDE:: "+event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode == 13) 
  {   
   caSearch();
  }  
 }
```

Please guide me to over come this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these attributes, which will make it impossible to select your edittext and will therefore deselect if for you.

`yourEditText.setFocusable( false );`

`yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode( false );`

Immediately afterwards, reverse these two prices of code

`yourEditText.setFocusable( true );`

`yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode( true );`

That should remove the cursor from search bar for you

Comment: i am developing application using phonegap.i am not using any native code.